# openid scope consent screen is not showing in spring authentication server

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

> I have configured my spring authentication server but the consent screen for **openid** is not showing but for other scopes such as **read** it is showing the consent screen what is the reason for this?

I have searched on the internet but did not find any solution could any one please help me and what if we want to show the consent screen for only particular scopes and not for other scopes is there a way to do that too?